# Open source alternative for ehcache with synchronousWrites for data consistency

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I'm using Ehcache 2.4 (release in April. 2011) for caching around 1 million items at ~3000put/sec.

Ehcache is build to detect data inconsistency on start and clean it up if it's the case. My main issue is I'm getting in this situation too often to be able using it properly.

Most of the time, my JVM shuts down too quickly (for many project related reasons) to let the CacheManager shut down properly. I have already tried to enable the ehCache hook.

Two question :

- On ehCache > 2.5, i saw a new option : "synchronousWrites", but it's an enterprise option ... So is there any others option I can try to have a stronger cache consistency with the non-enterprise version?
- Is there any others open-source Java cache, better than eHcache for cache consistency ?

Comment: Please provide more context. Probably you use the disk storage?

Comment: Do you actually want to cache these "1 million items" or is this a fixed size and you want to store them always completely?

Comment: Yes. I forgot this point, i'm using disk storage only. But i think there isn't performance issue there. 
These 1 million items is reach when everything is fine, as we use LRU eviction policy, it's an average.

Comment: The next weeks within march I will add persistence support to [cache2k](http://cache2k.org). OTOH I know that JBoss infinispan has persistence / storage support.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a look into this solution. I will share my feedback after.

Comment: Have a look at Apache Ignite.

Answer (score 1):

> Q. ... So is there any others option I can try to have a stronger cache consistency with the non-enterprise version?
>
> Q. Is there any others open-source Java cache, better than eHcache for cache consistency ?

*Ans.* Yes there is

You can try out [TayzGrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) and its replicated topology for stronger consistency if you're deploying it in a cluster. It synchronously replicates and is open source with Apache 2.0 license

You also have the option of using an In-Proc or Out-Proc client cache only or with a cluster with locking mechanism and [many more advance features](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/edition-comparison.html).

*Full disclosure: I work in TayzGrid so ask away if you have any questions :)*

Answer (score 0):

Jboss offers [infinispan](http://infinispan.org/) with many advanced caching features like distributed caching.  Infinispan Hot Rod Server can run as an individual process. Please have a check...

Answer (score 0):

Our open source Cacheonix http://www.cacheonix.org provides synchronous strict consistency for writes. It's the only consistency mode it has.